# If $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ and $\int_{a}^{\infty} g(x)dx$ converge conditionally, does $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$ absolutely converge?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

My question is:
Are there any two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ Which hold that $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ and$\int_{a}^{\infty} g(x)dx$ converge conditionally but  $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$ absolutely converges?

I know that if $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ and$\int_{a}^{\infty} g(x)dx$ converge conditionally then 
$\int_{a}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx $ and $\int_{a}^{\infty} |g(x)|dx$ diverges.
And if $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$ absolutely converges then $\int_{a}^{\infty} |f(x)g(x)|dx$ also converges.

Thanks.

Comment: Try $f(x)=g(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} / \lfloor x \rfloor$ or $f(x)=g(x)=\sin(x)/x$.

Comment: Take $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}$.  Then, $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}\,dx$ converges conditionally, but $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,dx$ diverges.

Comment: As yet another related possibility, if $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $g(x) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{x}}$, then $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx$ converge conditionally, and still $\int_0^\infty f(x) g(x)\,dx$ converges conditionally.

Comment: The title suggests "for all $f$ and $g$" while the body of the question suggests "there exist $f$ and $g$". It's good idea to edit one or the other (probably the title?) for posterity. <> Separately, if you can answer the analogous question for series, that example can be turned into an example with integrals.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
g(x)&=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt[4]{x}}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(x) +\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathbb{1}_{[1,\infty)}(x)\\
f(x)&=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(x) +\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathbb{1}_{[1,\infty)}(x)
\end{align}
Then
$$(fg)(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt[4]{x}}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(x) + \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\mathbb{1}_{[1,\infty)}(x)$$
is in integrable (in the sense of Lebesgue) and so absolutely integrable. Indeed,  both $f$ and $g$ are conditionally integrable in the sense that $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\int^a_0g$ and $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\int^a_0 f$ exists, but $\int^\infty_a|f|=\infty=\int^\infty_0|g|$. We have that
$$\int^\infty_0|fg|=\int^1_0|fg|+\int^\infty_1|fg|\leq \int^1_0\frac{dx}{x^{1/4}} +\int^\infty_1\frac{dx}{x^2}<\infty
$$